# connect domain name to localhost mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dns

I have mongodb set on my computer and I would like to access it with login/password from anywhere.
To do this I started js server and succeeded to connect the api from localhost:8000 with read, write etc.
But I can not "change" localhost to a domain name I own. I mean I get to it from my own computer, but it doesn't work on the others.
I also tried hosts file with "127.0.0.1       db.gpavlov.ru" but this didn't help either.

This is how my server.js looks like:

```
//server.js    
const express        = require('express');
    const MongoClient    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
    const db             = require('./config/db');
    const app            = express();
    const port = 80;

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://user123:12345678@46.34.141.192/MyDb", (err, database) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      require('./app/routes')(app, database);
      app.listen(port,  () => {
      console.log('We are live on ' + port);
      });
    })
```

the database - MyDb

Thank you for help !!

Comment: Maybe problem is host IP and PORT. Example : 46.34.141.192:3306

Comment: Do you mean you want mongo to listen externally on your host ? is it bound to an interface besides `lo` or do you have a firewall issue and can't connect from the outside? You question is not very clear so it's hard to know the exact problem you face.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Hi there ! aaammmm, how can i know that this is a firewall issue ?

Comment: I mean - when edittting the hosts file- i make the web site available only at local machine. or this can be used to set up router connection ?!^)